# Cheap and flexible switch with MACSec / NIC with MACSec support

Tags: networking, switch, security

I am looking for MACSec hardware for an academic project (layer 2 encryption). The main requirements are simplicity and a flexible key exchange configuration (however, it is not yet specified how the key exchange is done).

I am looking for a MACSec switch, and possibly also for a MACSec netword card.

Can you recommend some cheap commodity MACSec hardware?

Comment: I assume we're talking managed, probably with a web interface? How many ports are we talking? Do you need PoE? 10Gb SFPs?

Comment: Yes we are talking managed. A small number of ports is sufficient, speed does not matter, cost should be low. The only hard requirement is configurable MACSec support.